# Terminal returns nothing

Tags: python

this is the challenge :

This next function will give us the values from a list at every odd index. We will need to accept a list of numbers as an input parameter and loop through the odd indices instead of the elements. Here are the steps needed:

Define the function header to accept one input which will be our list of numbers
Create a new list which will hold our values to return
Iterate through every odd index until the end of the list
Within the loop, get the element at the current odd index and append it to our new list
Return the list of elements which we got from the odd indices.

and This is my solution :

```
def odd_indices(lst):
    odd_list = []
    index = 1
    while index % 2 != 0 and index < len(lst):
    odd_list.append(lst[index])
    index +=1
    return odd_list


print(odd_indices([4, 3, 7, 10, 11, -2]))
```

This doesnt return [3] only . can you help me figure out why ?

Comment: `while ( index % 2 != 0 and index < len (lst)) :` You never modify `index` so you have an endless loop.

Comment: Also, please [edit] and fix your indentation.

Comment: Hint: you are iterating through *all* the indices and check for odd ones. You can iterate over the odd ones directly by modifying `index` appropriately.

Comment: Or, the standard way to do this is to use `enumerate` and a `for` loop.

Comment: Your `while` loop is breaking the first time `index % 2 == 0`

Comment: Your indentation is still not right. And you modified the question by adding `index +=1`

Comment: Is there any way I can solve it with while ?

Comment: Just a `while` loop: `while index < len(lst): odd_list.append(lst[index]); index += 2`

Answer (score 0):

You check the parity in the loop control, instead of inside the loop.